# mysql is this query possible?

Tags: mysql

I need to write the following query so the "att" field is always a constant.

```
INSERT INTO index(id,val,att) (SELECT ID,val FROM product), 14;
```

"14" is a constant

how would i write it, if even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `index`(id,val,att) SELECT id,val,14 FROM product
```

*Index* is not a very good name for a table btw... You can use backquotes (`) to escape it, but better pick up another name.

Comment: i know, that name isnt even possible i think

Comment: VALUES is not needed on INSERT ... SELECT and the select does not need to be in parens.

Comment: oh thanks! it works even without VALUES. thanks everyone for such a quick response!

Answer (score 2):

Just add the constant in the `SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO `index`(id, val, att) (SELECT ID, val, 14 FROM product);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
INSERT INTO `index` (id,val,att) 
SELECT ID,val,14 FROM product
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply select a number and it will be returned. This should work:

```
INSERT INTO `index`(id,val,att) SELECT ID,val,14 FROM product;
```

Notes:

1. You do *NOT* need the values keyword for INSERT .. SELECT
   statements.
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html
2. As another person mentioned, index is not a great table name due to it being a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `Index`(id, val, att)
SELECT ID, val, 14 
FROM Product
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO index(id,val,att) VALUES (SELECT id,val,14 FROM product)
```

Try it

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO table_name(id,val,att) SELECT ID,val,14 FROM product

Dont use table name like index and there is no need for () in select from table.